# How to get Firestore document specific data Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My FIrestore data collections]

When I press a button I want to get that email address for my Text widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
void _onPressed() {
  Firestore.instance.collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data["email"]);
    });
  });
}
```

This will retrieve all the emails inside the collection.

---

If you know the document id, then you can do the following to retrieve one email specific to the document id:

```
  void _onPressed() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      print(value.data["email"]);
    });
  }
```

The above works assuming you have the `currentuserid` as a document id.

Comment: `document(firebaseUser.uid)` this part shows error.

Comment: "The above works assuming you have the currentuserid as a document id"

Comment: can I get document id from using userid. because my document id and userid are different

Comment: When adding documents to the database, u can use the Firebase uid as a document id

Answer (score -1):

You can use the where function if you know the email address you are looking.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: 'point@gmail.com');
```